# Php Curl Posting to .aspx

Tags: php, post

I am failing to post using curl in php to the url: http://example.com/sms/sms.aspx

The post string should be in the pattern:example.com/sms/sms.aspx?uid=9746674889&pwd=passwod&phone=9746674889&msg=hjgyjgKJKJK&provider=way2sms&send=SEND

If it is posted the output will Be 1 else -1

Can anyone help me in the curl part

```
<?php


//extract data from the post
  // extract($_GET);

           $uid = $_GET['uid'];
           $phone = $_GET['phone'];
           $pwd = $_GET['pwd'];
           $msg = $_GET['msg'];
           $provider = 'way2sms';


//set POST variables



$fields = array(
                            'uid'=>rawurlencode($uid),
                            'phone'=>rawurlencode($phone),
                            'pwd'=>rawurlencode($pwd),
                            'msg'=>rawurlencode($msg),
                            'provider'=>rawurlencode($provider)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

///curl part(please help)

?>
```

Comment: The post string should be in the fashion:ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=9746674889&pwd=passwod&phone=9746674889&msg=hjgyjgKJKJK&provider=way2sms&send=SEND <- Thats GET

Comment: The whole thing is GET, not POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic cURL POST script. It has no error handling - you should definitely [read the cURL manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
<?php

  // Destination URL
  $url = 'http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx';

  // Raw data to send
  $fields = array(
   'uid' => $_GET['uid'],
   'phone'=>$_GET['phone'],
   'pwd'=>$_GET['pwd'],
   'msg'=>$_GET['msg'],
   'provider'=>'way2sms'
  );

  // Build $fields into an encoded string
  $body = http_build_query($fields);

  // Initialise cURL
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  // Set options (post request, return body from exec)
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  // Do the request
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // Echo the result
  echo $result;
```

**EDIT**

Since what you actually want is GET and not POST, the code gets a lot simpler:

```
<?php

  // Destination URL
  $url = 'http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx';

  // Raw data to send
  $fields = array(
   'uid' => $_GET['uid'],
   'phone'=>$_GET['phone'],
   'pwd'=>$_GET['pwd'],
   'msg'=>$_GET['msg'],
   'provider'=>'way2sms'
  );

  // Build $fields into an encoded string and append to URL
  $url .= '?'.http_build_query($fields);

  // Initialise cURL
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  // Set options (post request, return body from exec)
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  // Do the request
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // Echo the result
  echo $result;
```

...or this whole thing could be done without cURL as:

```
<?php

  // Destination URL
  $url = 'http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx';

  // Raw data to send
  $fields = array(
   'uid' => $_GET['uid'],
   'phone'=>$_GET['phone'],
   'pwd'=>$_GET['pwd'],
   'msg'=>$_GET['msg'],
   'provider'=>'way2sms'
  );

  // Build $fields into an encoded string and append to URL
  $url .= '?'.http_build_query($fields);

  // Do the request
  $result = file_get_contents($url);

  // Echo the result
  echo $result;
```

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for curl_setopt() in /home/funzonem/public_html/service/api/sms.php on line 20

Warning: Wrong parameter count for curl_setopt() in /home/funzonem/public_html/service/api/sms.php on line 21. I am getting This Error

Comment: THe code is working.But still it fails to post. posted means the output should be 1. If I try to give the url directly to the browser it posts. This is the url http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=9746674889&pwd=password&phone=9746674889&msg=hjgyjgKJKJK&provider=way2sms&send=SEND

Comment: Right, in that case what you want is GET, not POST. You should read up on [HTTP methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and how they work so you know what you are dealing with. See edit above.

Comment: My host is not supporting the file_get_contents. Can u provide the curl code which can GET this url.

Comment: @sabin14 The first code in my edit should work. There are three versions above, use the middle one.